# static variables, creating new variables from classes in a static method inside my public class

Tags: java, static-methods, static-variables

ok this code was working earlier, but all of a sudden, java tells me that i can't reference the two stop objects (origin and destination) i'm trying to create in the loop from a static context,  but i'm not referencing them, i'm creating a new temporary object every iteration,  what am i missing here?  this method is inside my public class.
the error just says:  nonstatic variable cannot be referenced from a static context, where it says //problem areas

```
static void initializePassengers()
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NullPointerException
{
     FileReader fr = new FileReader(pathto+"passengers.csv");
     BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
     try { 
         while(!textReader.readLine().isEmpty()) {
             String temp=textReader.readLine();
             StringTokenizer te = new StringTokenizer(temp,",",false);
             String name=te.nextToken();
             Stop origin = new Stop(te.nextToken());  //problem area
             Stop destination = new Stop(te.nextToken()); //problem area
             allpassengers.add(new Passenger(name, origin, destination));
         }                
     } catch(NullPointerException e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }                     
     textReader.close();
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, and remove irrelevant code (including commented out bits). It's far too hard to read your question at the moment. Additionally, please post the *exact* error message, including where it occurs. Read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints for more hints.

Comment: That doesn't look fixed to me. It still looks all over the place to me. But it sounds like `te` is the problem... and you haven't told us anything about that.

Comment: How is the `Stop` class defined?  Is it an inner non-static class, or maybe an out-of-scope local class?

Comment: te is my tokenizer object, i instantiated to break apart temp,  Stop is a class of its own,  its constructors take one string and fills its fields up (name, idnumber) by looking it up in an external file.

Comment: Where's `pathto` defined? Is it static?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implying the problematic line is `allpassengers.add(new Passenger(name, origin, destination))`, 
I'm assuming `allpassengers` are a non-static member. You should make it static in order to access it from a static method.

Comment: i declared it in class scope like this static ArrayList<Passenger> allpassengers =new ArrayList<>();   the problem is the two lines that come before it

Comment: the exact problem is this: new Stop(te.nextToken());